# rewrite file content on button click in qt

Tags: c++, qt, file

Using QtCreator 3.0.0 based on Qt 5.2.0(MSVC 2010, 32bit).
I am trying to build a simple app for file handling; basically:
1- User pushes button -> dialog pops up.
2- User selects file(.txt) with plain text content.
3- App processes file and creates folder with many files(.txt) in it, in the same folder the selected file was.

So far, OK; now, if user (without restarting the app) re-does the previous 3 steps, the process repeats itself BUT this time the output has a flaw: the resulting files inside the created folder double their content, as in append the new content to the one that was already there, instead of deleting/emptying and then re-creating/re-populating themselves with the new content as desired.

I have tried deleting and/or emptying the files with:

```
//code fragment

input = new fstream();
output = new fstream();
address = dialog->selectedFiles().first();
input->open(address.toLatin1(), ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
QString results_folder_name = "RESULTS";

int lastSlash = address.lastIndexOf("/");
results = new QDir(address.left(lastSlash));
if(results->exists(results_folder_name)){
    results->cd(results_folder_name);
    results->setNameFilters(QStringList() << "*.*");
    results->setFilter(QDir::Files);
    foreach(QString dirFile, results->entryList()){
        results->remove(dirFile);
    }
}else{
    results->mkdir(results_folder_name);
    results->cd(results_folder_name);
}
```

Then there is a **WHILE** loop for creating and populating each of the resulting files,
I use the same variable *output* for each one (don't know how else to do it) and then I
`output.close();` and
`delete output;`
before the loop ends

ANY workaround will do, thanx

**EDITS:**
There were actually two ***while*** loops I had not included, the first (which I don't believe necessary to be included) is for iterating over the `input` variable and storing the information/strings in the variable **extensions**, *after* that comes the actual ***while*** loop where I iterate over that variable and distribute the contents in the resulting files, like this:

```
QMap<QString, QStringList>::const_iterator i = extensions.constBegin();  
while(i != extensions.constEnd()){
   QString newExtensionPath = results.absolutePath() + '/' + i.key() + ".txt";
   output.open(newExtensionPath.toLatin1(), ios_base::out | ios_base::binary | ios_base::trunc);
   if(output.is_open()){
      QStringList value = i.value();
      while(!value.empty()){
         QString first = value.takeFirst();
         output.write(first.toLatin1(), first.size());
         output.write("\n", 1);
      }
   } else{msg.setText("error");msg.exec();}
   output.close();
   i++;
}
delete output;
```

Now, remember, this code throws no errors or anything like that, it would work like a charm if what I wanted was for the content to be appended to each file instead of re-written (which is what I actually need).

And, very important:
1- If I keep on repeating the process WITHOUT RESTARTING THE APP(closing the app window and Ctrl+R again on Qt) the files DO GET DELETED (I check on them every time) but when created again, the content is doubled, tripled, quadrupled, etc.
2- If I DO RESTART THE APP, every time it runs the algorithm for the first time it works ok.

Please tell me if it's too messy so I explain it better.

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`trunc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) mode for the output stream to overwrite content of the existent file:

```
output->open("TargetFileToWrite.bin", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary | ios_base::trunc);
```

In this mode content of the file will be discarded when stream opening. `open` method fails if both `ios_base::trunc | ios_base::app` specified.

*UPDATE:*

Looks like your `extensions` map is not cleaned up after you finish output to the files. Content kept there and it's doubled, tripled, etc when the algorithm is restarted. Add `extensions.clear()` after the `while` loop.

Comment: i add `ios_base::trunc` and then `output->is_open()` returns false, thus ending the entire process before it even starts

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría Looks like you also have `ios_base::app` (append) flag specified. You should remove it to use `ios_base::trunc`.

Comment: I really don´t, what I have is what I posted, sorry for the delayed reply. I am really stuck here, do you happen to have a different approach to solve this?thanx

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría I have on more idea. Updated the answer, please check.

Comment: did that last two, nothing. thanx for the effort, though

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría Please post the larger code fragment. `while` loop with the logic is required to analyse the problem.

Comment: edited question with **while** loop and further explanations

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría Seems I understand the reason, please check the *Update* section in the answer.